# Opening A Single Chrome Tab Causes Multiple Remote Connections

Tags: google-chrome, sockets, tcp, connection, netstat

While working on a project, I've observed that, if a open a single `Chrome` tab, there are multiple `socket connections` being made. Ideally I assumed, there should be only one connection, that is from my local machine to the google server.

Here is the `netstat` results of multiple remote connections made:

[image: Connections Image]

Why are there many connections made instead of one? Please clear this doubt for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you open a Chrome tab, it will load not only one resources from the internet(maybe not just from Google). You can use some HTTP/S request capture tools like `fiddler` or `HTTP Analyzer` to see those requests.